# Rasa Webchat + docker showing blank

Tags: rasa

I have setup rasa using docker, but I am not able to open webchat. It seems to connect but the page remains blank.

Following are the steps to replicate;

```
#create the directory
mkdir rasatest && cd  rasatest


#Init the project
sudo docker run -it --rm --user 1000 -v $(pwd)/app:/app rasa/rasa:latest-full init --no-prompt


#Change right for docker to work properly
cd .. && chmod -R  777 rasatest  && cd  rasatest

#Change credentials as follows
nano app/credentials.yml

    socketio:
      user_message_evt: user_uttered
      bot_message_evt: bot_uttered
      session_persistence: true

docker run --name=rasatest --user 1000 -v $(pwd)/app/app:/app -p "5005:5005" rasa/rasa:latest-full run -m models --enable-api --cors "*" --debug
```

I am using the latest Rasa webchat and I have followed the instruction on how to set it and below is my code for the webchat.;

```
<html>

<body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat"></script>
    <script>

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {

            !(function () {
                let e = document.createElement("script"),
                    t = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
                (e.src =
                    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/rasa-webchat/lib/index.js"),
                    (e.async = !0),
                    (e.onload = () => {
                        window.WebChat.default(
                            {
                                customData: { language: "en" },
                                socketUrl: "http://localhost:5005",
                                // add other props here
                                initPayload: "/get_started",
                                socketPath: "/socket.io/",
                                embedded: true,
                                title: "Welcome",
                                subtitle: "to my chatbot",
                                params: { "storage": "session" } // can be set to "local"  or "session". details in storage section.
                            },
                            null
                        );
                    }),
                    t.insertBefore(e, t.firstChild);
            })();

        });

    </script>
</body>


</html>
```

The page is totally blank and on inspecting the page it looks as follows.

```
<div id="rasaWebchatPro">
      <div class="" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I change the chat page to https://github.com/scalableminds/chatroom I able to chat.

Is there an issue with rasa-webchat?

Comment: If I change the chat page to following chatting interfaces it is working. 

-  https://github.com/scalableminds/chatroom
-  https://github.com/JiteshGaikwad/Chatbot-Widget


What could be the issue rasa-webchat?

Comment: Is there a way to change rasa-webchat from socket to webhook?

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the two below:

- https://github.com/scalableminds/chatroom
- https://github.com/JiteshGaikwad/Chatbot-Widget